# Set maximum number of table of contents in the header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I'm doing my presentation in beamer and I use warsaw theme. I have around 5-6 sections and they are all mentioned at the top of every page. **This makes available frame space smaller.** Can I limit this number by 3? For example, to show previous, current and next sections.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]

  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 3}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 4}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 5}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Version 1

Hi you could alter the macro which inserts the navigation list.

```
    \documentclass{beamer}

    \makeatletter
    \def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
      \hbox to #1{%
        \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
         \vskip0.5625ex%
        \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
         \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
           \ifnum##5=\c@part%
           \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
           \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
           \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
           \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
             \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                 \hskip0.3cm%
                 \ifnum\c@section=##1%
                 {\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}}%
                 \else%
                   {%
                   \advance\c@section by  -1 %
                     \ifnum##1 = \c@section%
                     \usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}%
                    \else%
                    \advance\c@section by  2 %
                     \ifnum##1 = \c@section%
                   \usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}%
                   \else
                   \fi
                   \fi
                   }%
                 \fi\hskip0.3cm}}}%
           \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex\dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
           \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
         \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}
    \makeatother


      \usetheme{Warsaw}
      \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}


    \begin{document}
    \section{Test 1}
    \begin{frame} \end{frame}
    \section{Test 2}
    \begin{frame} \end{frame}
    \section{Test 3}
    \begin{frame} \end{frame}
    \section{Test 4}
    \begin{frame} \end{frame}
    \section{Test 5}
    \begin{frame} \end{frame}

    \end{document}

Here two new conditionals are introduced, which check for the distance between the active section (stored in `\c@section`) and the printed sections. 

The result is this:

![enter image description here][1]
```

### Version 2

This version provides a better fit to the size of three lines. Please note, that the height of the colored beamer box is adjusted manually.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}


\makeatletter
       \newcount\c@p
       \newcount\c@m
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5625ex%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \c@p=\c@section%
       \c@m=\c@section%
       \advance\c@m by -1 %
       \advance\c@p by 1 %
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
              \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
             \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@m%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                 {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}
                 %
                \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@p%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
               {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
               %
               \else%
               %
               \fi%
               \fi%
               %
            \fi%%
            %

      \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex%
       \dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}%{split theme} % full manual adjustment
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=3em%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}



\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 3}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 4}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 5}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Again the if structure picks the wanted entries. But in this case the box is only filled when needed. I also introduced two helper variables `c@p` and `c@m` to avoid too complicated grouping. 
This renders to:

[image]

and the following frame will look like this:

[image]

### Version 3

Now featuring three navigation elements at any time:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}


\makeatletter
       \newcount\c@p
       \newcount\c@m
              \newcount\c@pp
       \newcount\c@mm
\def\insertsectionnavigation#1{%
  \hbox to #1{%
    \vbox{{\usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{section in head/foot}%
     \vskip0.5625ex%
    \def\slideentry##1##2##3##4##5##6{}%
     \def\sectionentry##1##2##3##4##5{%
       \ifnum##5=\c@part%
       \def\insertsectionhead{##2}%
       \def\insertsectionheadnumber{##1}%
       \def\insertpartheadnumber{##5}%
       \c@p=\c@section%
       \c@m=\c@section%
      \c@pp=\c@section%
       \c@mm=\c@section%
       \advance\c@m by -1 %
       \advance\c@p by 1 %
       \advance\c@mm by -2 %
       \advance\c@pp by 2 %
       %     
       \ifnum \c@section=1
                    \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
              \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
             \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@p%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                 {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}
                 %
                \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@pp%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
               {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
               %
               \else%
               %
               \fi%
               \fi%
               %
            \fi%%  
         \else%
  \ifnum \c@section=\beamer@sectionmax
               \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
              \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
             \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@m%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                 {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}
                 %
                \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@mm%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
               {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
               %
               \else%
               %
               \fi%
               \fi%
               %
            \fi%%
       \else%
             \ifnum\c@section=##1%
               \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
              \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
             {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
             \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@m%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
                 {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}
                 %
                \else%
                 \ifnum##1=\c@p%
                 \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{%
                  \hyperlink{Navigation##3}{\hbox to #1{%
               {\hskip0.3cm\usebeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}\hskip0.3cm}}}}%
               %
               \else%
               %
               \fi%
               \fi%
               %
            \fi%%
            %
            \fi
            \fi
            %

      \ht\beamer@tempbox=1.6875ex%
       \dp\beamer@tempbox=0.75ex%
       \box\beamer@tempbox\fi}%
     \dohead\vskip0.5625ex}}\hfil}}


\setbeamertemplate{headline}%{split theme} % full manual adjustment
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=3em%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.825ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsubsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}



\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test 1}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 2}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 3}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 4}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}
\section{Test 5}
\begin{frame} \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It important to say that his is hard coded. This applies on 3 elements only and is not quite versatile. What it does is easy: it checks if the current frame is the first or last and inserts the navigation accordingly.

I want to add that this kind of navigation is very reader unfriendly. One has to look very carefully to understand it.

The first slide would look like this:

[image]

Comment: it's just great, thanks! I love latex, but when I need to write 60 lines of code to implement such simple request, it drives me crazy... I'm wondering if there is standard solution for this.

Comment: I didn't write all those lines. I just altered the original definition. That makes app. 15 loc to write. A standard solution won't never exist in the world of latex. At least for such high level things like here there is always a alternative way. If you're looking for an option... well someone has to implement it. And  i think (qualified) help is always wellcome ;)

Comment: hello, could you tell me please how I can add 2 logo images to this customized header? I tried adding \includegraphics into \setbeamertemplate{headline}, but compilation fails..